# Bound on $\mathbb P[X=0]$ using Paley-Zygmund and Chebyshev

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, solution-verification

In an exercise I am asked to show that if a non negative random variable $X$ satisfies $\frac{\mathbb E [X^2]}{\mathbb E[X]^2}\ge 2$ and $\text{Var}(X)<\infty$, then Paley-Zygmund gives a tighter upper bound on $\mathbb P[X=0]$ than Chebyshev.

Paley-Zygmund: $\mathbb P[X\ge\theta \mathbb EX]\ge (1-\theta)^2\frac{\mathbb E[x]^2}{\mathbb E[X^2]}$ holds for any $\theta\in[0,1]$.

Chebyshev: $\mathbb P[|X-\mathbb E X|\ge t]\le\frac{\text{Var}(X)}{t^2}$

The way to use Chebyshev is to set $t= \mathbb E X$ and get $\mathbb P[X=0]\le \mathbb P[|X-\mathbb E X|\ge \mathbb E X]\le \frac{\text{Var}(X)}{\mathbb E[X]^2}=\frac{\mathbb E[X^2]}{\mathbb E[X]^2}-1$

For P-Z, since it is true if we replace $\ge$ by $>$, and by setting $\theta=0$, we can write $\mathbb P[X=0]=1-\mathbb P[X>0]\le 1-\frac{\mathbb E[X]^2}{\mathbb E[X^2]}$

**But** in both cases we cannot use the $\frac{\mathbb E [X^2]}{\mathbb E[X]^2}\ge 2$ assumption. We could use it if the inequality was flipped (and it would give 0.5 and 1 respectively for P-Z and Chebyshev)... unless I am doing something wrong.

Also, can we use $\theta>1$ if $\frac{(\mathbb E X)}{\sqrt{\mathbb E(X^2)}}<\frac{1}{\theta -1}$ ?

Comment: In a way, the Paley-Zygmund inequality is definitively tighter: the upper bound in Chebyshev's inequality is at least 1 and the upper bound in Paley-Zygmund is always less than 1.

Comment: @Ankitp How did you get to your conclusion about the P-Z bound? I get that the Chebyshev bound is at least 1 and the P-Z bound is at least $1/2$ but it could be $5$... Whereas the problem asks to show that it is *for sure* better than the Chebyshev bound.

Comment: How can you get 5? We are subtracting something positive from 1.

Comment: Yes we are substracting something which is at most 1/2 from one, so the result is at least 1/2, and I just said it could be anything above 1/2, like 5. But I totally ignored that fact that that fraction is non negative

Comment: I think the intention behind the question is that for any finite value of $E [X^2]$ in the specified range, Paley-Zygmund gives a non-vacuous bound while Chebyhev gives a vacuous result.

Comment: Also, P-Z is tight for certain cases. For example, consider this random variable: $X = 0$ with prob. $1- \delta$ and $1/\delta$ with prob. $\delta$. In this case $E X = 1$ and $E X^2 = 1/\delta$. We get that $P(X= 0) = 1 - \delta = 1  -  \frac{(E X)^2}{E X^2}$. Thus P-Z is tight in this family. It also shows that one can't expect a "better" upper bound than what you have in general.